# VQMod stopped working

Tags: opencart

I am using Open cart V.1.5.3.1. My VqMod stopped working suddenly( i have installed 1.Ajax-Enable-Disable-Product, 2.vqmod_admin_ajax_edit_quantity both of which are not working.) I have tried reinstalling the VQMod, but the problem still exists.
Even on my local machine using MAMP, the VQMod has stopped functioning.
Please help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure the vqmod folder and the vqmod/vqcache folders are writable (either 755 or 777).

```
Also be sure index.php and admin/index.php are writable.
    If not sure which you need, first try 755.
    If you get errors about permissions, then try 777.
```